# How do I specify default option with an ASP.Net Core @Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a .cshtml file that looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.MyModel.YesNoQuestion,                    // IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo))),   // Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>,
    "No",    // IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> selectList (can be "null")
    new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "MyModel.YesNoQuestion" }  // object htmlAttributes
)
```

Unfortunately, the resulting dropdown looks like this:

```
No
Yes
No
```

The rendered HTML looks like this in Chrome Developer tools:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="MyModel_YesNoQuestion" name="MyModel.YesNoQuestion">
  <option value>No</option>
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="MyModel_YesNoQuestion" name="MyModel.YesNoQuestion">
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option selected>No</option>
</select>
```

Q: How do I specify the default option in an ASP.Net Core DropdownListFor?

Q: What exactly does the third argument, "No", do?  Argument 2 ("new SelectList") generates my dropdown, so what is Argument 3 supposed to be used for?

Comment: Some small note on your code: is there a reason why you use tag helpers in stead of the more readable Razor syntax?

Comment: @Jordy Deweer - I'm certainly open to the suggestion :)  Would you mind posting an example as a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: How do I specify the default option in an ASP.Net Core
> DropdownListFor?

The Html.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty> extension method is a strongly typed extension method generates  element for the property specified using a lambda expression.

To set the default selected value, we could set it via the first Parameter, .cshtml.cs page code like this:

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        } 
        [BindProperty]
        public YesNo YesNo { get; set; }   //Enum type, used to set the dropdownlist options
        [BindProperty]
        public string YesNoSelected { get; set; } //used to get the Dropdownlist seleted value.
        public void OnGet()
        {
            YesNoSelected = ((int)YesNo.Yes).ToString();  //set the default selected value.
        }
    }
    public enum YesNo
    {
        No, Yes
    }
```

Code in the .cshtml page: here we have to bind the DropDownList using the **Value** and **Text** property, then, we can based on the selected value to set default values:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YesNoSelected,     // IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo)).OfType<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(YesNo), x),
                Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString(),
            }), "Value", "Text"),   // Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>,
            //"Select Options",    // IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> selectList (can be "null")
            new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "Model.YesNoQuestion" }  // object htmlAttributes
        )
```

Besides, you could also set the default value via the **[SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)** method (using the last parameter to set the selected Value), try to use the following code:

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        } 
        [BindProperty]
        public YesNo YesNo { get; set; }   //Enum type, used to set the dropdownlist options
        [BindProperty]
        public string YesNoSelected { get; set; } //used to get the Dropdownlist seleted value.
        public void OnGet()
        { 
           // YesNoSelected = ((int)YesNo.Yes).ToString();  //set the default selected value.
        }
    }
    public enum YesNo
    {
        No, Yes
    }
```

Code in the .cshtml page:

```
    @page
    @model IndexModel 

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YesNoSelected,     // IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo)).OfType<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(YesNo), x),
                Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString(),
            }), "Value", "Text", ((int)YesNo.Yes).ToString()),   // Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>, //set default selected value.
            //"Select Options",    // IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> selectList (can be "null")
            new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "Model.YesNoQuestion" }  // object htmlAttributes
        )
```

The output as below:

[image]

> Q: What exactly does the third argument, "No", do? Argument 2 ("new
> SelectList") generates my dropdown, so what is Argument 3 supposed to
> be used for?

The third parameter is optional, which will be the first item of the DropDownList. Generally, we could use the add the description or prompt, like this:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YesNoSelected,     // IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo)).OfType<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(YesNo), x),
                Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString(),
            }), "Value", "Text", ((int)YesNo.Yes).ToString()),   // Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>,
            "Select Yes or No",    // IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> selectList (can be "null")
            new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "Model.YesNoQuestion" }  // object htmlAttributes
        )
```

The result as shown below:

[image]

If you don't want to add this option, just remove it.

**Edit:**

Using JavaScript/JQuery method to set the DropDownList default selected value:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YesNoSelected,     // IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo)).OfType<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(YesNo), x),
                Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString(),
            }), "Value", "Text"),   // Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>,
            //"Select Yes or No",    // IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> selectList (can be "null")
            new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "Model_YesNoQuestion" }  // object htmlAttributes
        )

    <input type="hidden" id="ddldefault" value="1" />

    @section Scripts{
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { 
                var ddldefault = $("#ddldefault").val(); //default selected value.
                $("#Model_YesNoQuestion option").each(function (index, item) {
                    //You could also use the text() method to check whether the option is selected or not.
                    if ($(item).val() == ddldefault) {
                        $(item).attr("selected", "selected");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(item).removeAttr("selected");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script> 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  1) You completely answered my question about the "3rd parameter" - great explanation!  2) Setting the default with "SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)" sounds promising, 3) I cannot, unfortunately, mess with the view model in the .cs file.  Because the design I inherited doesn't "[BindProperty]" to individual fields.  No.  Instead, there are multiple EF objects, each having 10s or 100s of fields.  I can't mess with the underlying EF class files; I can't replicate the EF code for my .cshtml.cs view model. I'm stuck with modifying the .cshtml.

Comment: @FoggyDay, you could also try to use JQuery/JavaScript script to set the DropDownList default selected value, check the Edit code.

Comment: I wound up adapting your SelectList() syntax - and it works like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tag helpers, use razor syntax.

Your .cshtml looks like this:

```
@model SettingsViewModel

<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <label asp-for="YesNo">Yes or no?</label>
    <select asp-for="YesNo" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<YesNoOptions>()"></select>
</form>
```

Your SettingsViewModel.cs likte his:

```
    public class SettingsViewModel
    {
        public YesNoOptions YesNo { get; set; } = YesNoOptions.No;
    }
```

And the YesNoOtpions enum like this:

```
    public enum YesNoOptions
    {
        No, Yes
    }
```

As you can see, you still need to set a default value in the view model, as @Mika Tähtinen mentioned in the first answer.

Comment: 1) Thank you for clarifying what you meant by "razor syntax".  The "@Html" syntax ("Html helpers") is basically legacy syntax, correct?  2) I'm trying to build on legacy code I've inherited.  I *don't* want to mess around with the "model" if I can at all avoid it.  Because it looks like this: `[BindProperty] public ReallyBigEFModel1 Answers1 { get; set; }; [BindProperty] public ReallyBigEFModel2 Answers2 { get; set; }...`  It would be great if I could just set the stupid default in my .cshtml markup...

Comment: @FoggyDay - Hmmm, I don't think there's another way. You can, however, add some JavaScript to select the default value without altering the model class? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The third argument is for giving an default empty item, so it's not what you want. To get "No" selected by default, you need to set YesNoQuestion in your model to No when you initialize it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an option.  For several reasons. Q: Are there any good ways to specify the default option directly in my .cshtml markup?  And ensure the value (default or manually selected) is correctly written to the underlying model object?